# In R: How can I loop through all possible "omitted categories" in a regression with indicator variables?

Tags: r, binary, logistic-regression, dummy-variable, indicator

I want to run the regression as follows:

```
 mylogit1 <- glm(MyDepVar ~ 10indicators * 3indicators   , data = data, family = "binomial")
 summary(mylogit1)
 plot_model(mylogit1, type = "int", title = "Omitted category 1/1", show.legend = TRUE,
            transform = "plogis", show.values = T, dot.size = 5, line.size = 1.5, value.offset = .3, colors = "Paired") +
   theme_sjplot()
```

However, the variables 10indicators and 3indicators are indicators. They form subsets of the data. Usually 1 is an omitted baseline category (10 possible choice for baseline in 10indicators, 3 possible baseline choices in 3indicators).

Can I automate the variation in baselines in R and (bonus) plot all the respective figures using sjplot package?

I really struggle to automatically change another baseline each time.

Thanks in advance for any prompters!

Comment: For better syntax, consider changing the names to have them not start with a number

Comment: You can always use the `C` command. Though one linear regression is enough. You do not need to change the base as the results is the same. eg `lm(Sepal.Length~C(Species, base = 2), iris)`

Comment: Thank you, I will put the number last. The results depend on the baseline, if you do not have a natural control but try to make many comparisons between different groups (re: interaction). Thanks!